# How to get a UI variable out of a function

Tags: javascript, function, user-interface

I'm sorry if this is basic.  I'm self taught and stuggle with what are probably simple features of Javascript programming.  Can anyone show me what I should be searching for to find the right kind of answer, OR help me in general with this one?

I have a function inside a UI window to quickly populate it with panels.  But I can't seem to get the values entered into each panel get OUT of the UI and into the main "DoSomething" function.
The variable (dlg.tryThis) won't update?  Why? What do I need to do?

```
// making a simple UI
function UI_Builder(doSomething)
{
    var dlg = new Window( "dialog", "options" );
    dlg.mainGroup = dlg.add( "group", undefined,"main" );

//Created a simple function so I can re-create panels and values very easy
    function makePanel (panelName, val)  {
        var newPanel = eval("dlg.mainGroup." + panelName);
        newPanel = dlg.mainGroup.add( 'panel', undefined, panelName );
        newPanel.Start = newPanel.add("edittext", [0,0,30,20], val);
        dlg.Start = newPanel.Start.text
        newPanel.Start.onChanging = function()                
                { 
                 dlg.Start = newPanel.Start.text
                  alert("Changed " + panelName + " to:  " + dlg.Start) // THIS alerts correctly.  It know what value I changed and where I changed it. 
                 return dlg.Start;
                 } 
            return dlg.Start;
        } 

    // calling the function to create panels.
    dlg.tryThis = makePanel("tryThis", 4); 
    dlg.anotherOne = makePanel("anotherOne",  3); 
    dlg.again = makePanel("again", 2); 

    dlg.mainGroup.btnCancel = dlg.mainGroup.add( "button",[0,0,130,70], "doSomething" );
    dlg.mainGroup.btnCancel.onClick = function()
    {  
        doSomething();  
     }
 return dlg
}

// all the UI builder is doing is showing the UI
var dlg = UI_Builder(doSomething);
dlg.show();

function doSomething()
{
dlg.close();

alert(dlg.tryThis)  // this is not the NEW value?   How do I get it to be the NEW value updated by the ".onChanging" function? 
}
```

Comment: `eval` is **evil** - `dlg.mainGroup[panelName]` will give you the same

Comment: What is the UI library that you used?

Answer (score 0):

try passing `dlg` to the event handler instead of declaring it globally:

```
dlg.mainGroup.btnCancel.onClick = function() {
    doSomething(dlg);  
}

function doSomething(dlg) {
    dlg.close();
    alert(dlg.tryThis);
}
```

If you take this approach you should not declare `var dlb` globally, to avoid confusion. (Shadowing variables is generally a bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling doSomething without any context.

Use func.apply:

```
dlg.mainGroup.btnCancel.onClick = function()
{  
    doSomething.apply(this, []);
}
```

And handle the object as 'this':

```
function doSomething()
{
    this.close();
    alert(this.tryThis)  // this is not the NEW value?   How do I get it to be the NEW value updated by the ".onChanging" function? 
}
```